# VHDL , Spartan-3AN output

Tags: vhdl, spartan

I have this design which basically about a multifunctional calender that have the following features:

1. displays the date in this [ format year/month/day : hours : minutes : seconds ]
2. Stop watch.
3. Alarm .
4. A Snooz option when the alarm is active , and you can change the snooz period or you can stop the alarm .
5. events , to be saved in a selected date and time and when it occur an alarm will be enabled.

this is what i have done for calculating the clock [ hours : minutes : seconds ]

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Clock is
port (clk : in std_logic;
      seconds : out integer ;
      minutes : out integer;
      hours : out integer
     );
end Clock;

architecture Behavioral of Clock is
        signal sec,min : integer range 0 to 60 := 0 ;
        signal hour : integer range 0 to 24 := 0 ;
begin
        seconds <= sec;
        minutes <= min;
        hours <= hour;

        process (clk)
        begin
            if (clk'event and clk='1') then
                sec <=sec+1 ;
                if (sec=60) then 
                    min <= min+1 ;
                    sec <= 0 ;
                    if (min=60) then 
                        hour <= hour +1;
                        min<=0;
                        if ( hour = 24) then
                            hour <= 0;
                        end if;
                    end if ;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process ;

end Behavioral;
```

and this code to do the rest date information [Year/month/day] ...

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity calender is
   port (
        clk : in std_logic;
      LYear     : in  std_logic;
      O_DAYS_IN_MONTH : out unsigned(4 downto 0)
      );
end entity calender;

architecture Behavioral of calender is

    signal hours :integer;
    signal Mday,day : integer range 1 to 31:=1;
    signal month: integer range 1 to 12:=1;
    signal year : integer range 2010 to 2030 :=2010;

begin
    u0 : entity work.Clock port map ( clk => clk , hours => hours );

    process ( clk,hours )
    begin 
        if (clk'event and clk='1') then
            if ( hours = 23 ) then 
                day <= day +1 ;
                if ( day = Mday ) then 
                    day <= 1;
                    month <= month +1 ;
                    if ( month = 13 ) then 
                        month <= 1 ;
                        year <= year +1;
                        if ( year = 2030 ) then 
                            year <= 2010;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process ( month , LYear)
    begin
        if ( month = 9  or month = 4 or month = 6 or  month = 11) then 
            Mday <= 30;
        elsif ( month = 2 and LYear = '0') then 
            Mday <= 28 ;
        elsif ( month = 2 and LYear = '1') then 
            Mday <= 29;
        else 
            Mday <= 31;
        end if;
    end process;

   O_DAYS_IN_MONTH <= to_unsigned( Mday ,O_DAYS_IN_MONTH'length) ;                   

end architecture Behavioral;
```

I'v also the coded for the stop watch independently , that out puts on the 7-Segment in the spartan 3 which is the following ...

```
library IEEE;                                                       
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity stop_watch is
port(
        clr: in std_logic;
        strt: in std_logic;
        clk : in std_logic;
        anode : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        seg : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
        ); 
end stop_watch ;

architecture Behavioral of stop_watch is
    signal dig1,dig2,dig3,dig4:std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    signal clk10hz,clk1khz:std_logic;
begin


    process (clr,strt,clk10hz)
        variable d1,d2,d4:integer range 0 to 10;
        variable d3:integer range 0 to 6;
     begin
        if(clr='1')then
            d1:=0;
            d2:=0;
            d3:=0;
            d4:=0;
        elsif(clk10hz'event and clk10hz='1') then
            if(strt='0')then
                d1:=d1;
                d2:=d2;
                d3:=d3;
                d4:=d4;
            else
                d1:= d1+1;
                if(d1=10)then
                    d1:=0;
                    d2:=d2+1;
                end if;
                if(d2=10)then
                    d3:=d3+1;
                    d2:=0;
                end if;
                if(d3=6)then
                    d4:=d4+1;
                    d3:=0;
                end if; 
                if(d4=10)then
                    d4:=0;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if; 


        case d1 is 
            when 0 => dig1 <="10000001";
            when 1 => dig1 <="11001111";
            when 2 => dig1 <="10010010";
            when 3 => dig1 <="10000110";
            when 4 => dig1 <="11001100";
            when 5 => dig1 <="10100100";
            when 6 => dig1 <="10100000";
            when 7 => dig1 <="10001111";
            when 8 => dig1 <="10000000";
            when 9 => dig1 <="10001100";
            when 10 => dig1 <="10000001";
        end case;

        case d2 is
            when 0 => dig2 <="00000001";
            when 1 => dig2 <="01001111";
            when 2 => dig2 <="00010010";
            when 3 => dig2 <="00000110";
            when 4 => dig2 <="01001100";
            when 5 => dig2 <="00100100";
            when 6 => dig2 <="00100000";
            when 7 => dig2 <="00001111";
            when 8 => dig2 <="00000000";
            when 9 => dig2 <="00001100";
            when 10 => dig2 <="00000001";
        end case;

        case d3 is 
            when 0 => dig3 <="10000001";
            when 1 => dig3 <="11001111";
            when 2 => dig3 <="10010010";
            when 3 => dig3 <="10000110";
            when 4 => dig3 <="11001100";
            when 5 => dig3 <="10100100";
            when 6 => dig3 <="10100000";
        end case;

        case d4 is
            when 0 => dig4 <="00000001";
            when 1 => dig4 <="01001111";
            when 2 => dig4 <="00010010";
            when 3 => dig4 <="00000110";
            when 4 => dig4 <="01001100";
            when 5 => dig4 <="00100100";
            when 6 => dig4 <="00100000";
            when 7 => dig4 <="00001111";
            when 8 => dig4 <="00000000";
            when 9 => dig4 <="00001100";
            when 10 => dig4 <="00000001";
        end case;
    end process;


    process (clk)
        Variable Count: integer range 0 to 5000000 :=0;
    begin
        if (Clk'event and Clk ='1') then
            count := count+1;
            if ( count < 2500000 ) then
                clk10Hz <= '0';
            elsif (count = 2500000) then
                clk10Hz <= '1';
            elsif (count = 5000000) then
                clk10Hz <= '0' ; count := 0;
            end if; 
        end if;
    end process ;


    process (clk1Khz)
        variable cnt : integer range 0 to 3:= 0;
    begin
        if (clk1Khz'event and clk1Khz='1') then
            case cnt is
                when 0 => anode <="1110";
                    seg<= dig1;
                    cnt:=cnt+1;
                when 1 => anode <="1101";
                    seg<= dig2;
                    cnt:=cnt+1;
                when 2 => anode <="1011";
                    seg<= dig3;
                    cnt:=cnt+1;
                when 3 => anode <="0111";
                    seg <= dig4;
                    cnt:=0;
                end case;
        end if;
   end process;


    process (clk)
        Variable Count: integer range 0 to 50000 :=0;
    begin
        if (Clk'event and Clk ='1') then
            count := count+1;
            if ( count < 25000 ) then
                clk1Khz <= '0';
            elsif (count = 25000) then
                clk1Khz <= '1';
            elsif (count = 50000) then
                clk1Khz <= '0' ; count := 0;
            end if; 
        end if;
    end process ;


end     Behavioral;
```

Now , My problem is ..

I'm supposed to out put all this information's on the LCD display in the spartan 3-AN , which i totally have no experience with , i know that my code still not finished yet and still have to do some clock divisions as i did in the stop watch code , and i know that the clock divisions will be changed when interaction with the LCD so i didn't bother writing it in my code write now.
If anyone can give me any informations about how to deal with the LCD display , how to display characters , how move from character to another so i can change it when an event happens from a keyboard.

You can say that i have 0 experience with dealing with that LCD in Spartan 3AN , i have tried to see the [user guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug334.pdf) for the board that xilinx provided and i have understood some few things from it but still don't know how to use it , if there is any tutorial that can help will be more than enough for me.

Comment: The user guide more or less has everything you need. Try reading it again, and start trying things out. If you need more information on the interface, try doing a google search for HD44780 (which is an equivalent, and very very common, LCD controller chip).

Comment: You don't need to reinvent the wheel. E.g. opencores lists several LCD controllers such as this http://opencores.org/project,16x2_lcd_controller

Comment: sonicwave ... ok then , i will give it another shot , if nothing again then i will look for that search you talked about , thanks mate .

Comment: Paebbels ... it's asking me for a log in that needs validation that will take 1-2 days :/ , but thanks mate will look at it after validation o/

Comment: If you look at the question titled [Weird VHDL Behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430643/weird-vhdl-behavior) here on Stackoverflow, there's the code for an almost working driver provided.  The answer by Galland and it's comments explain what needs to be corrected.  This was found by searching stackoverflow using *[vhdl] lcd*, there are 28 results, I scanned 3/4 before finding it.  The opencores controller uses to 128 bit std_logic_vectors as line buffers while the linked SO question simply writes sequential characters.